# confirmation for link_to not working rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, web

I have the following code-

```
<td><%= link_to "", {:controller => :daily_work_updates, :action => :deleteValue, :id => a.UPDATE_ID}, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} , :class=>'glyphicon glyphicon-trash'%></td>
```

When I click on the link. The action is successfully done but the confirmation pop up does not show for some reason. I have looked up similar questions but none have seemed to help me.

I am using rails 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I was missing the Unobtrusive scripting adapter for jQuery (jquery_ujs) in my application.js

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```